# Sublime exclude file extension in "File Search"

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to exclude a particular extension while doing a `Search in Files...` search:

- `Ctrl + Shift + f`  in Windows/Linux
- `Cmd + Shift + f` in MacOS

I know it would be convenient to include extension rather excluding but  have so many extensions lets say 10 but it is tough to include 9 extensions like *.py,*.xml,*.html...

I only want to ignore file 1 extension.

anybody have any solutions??!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The option to exclude a file extension in a 'Find in Files...' search is built into the tool.

Click on the ellipsis (...) to the right of the 'Where" box and one of the options is `Add Exclude Filter`.

[image: Sublime Text screenshot]

This seems to do exactly what I think you are asking for.

Comment: yes my friend this is what exactly i asked for :)  THANKS

Answer (score 1):

To add excluded file extensions in the Find in Files *Where* dialogue by typing rather than clicking, prefix the extension to exclude with a dash/minus character: `-`

e.g., this helps you search in `.js` files but exclude the minimised versions:

`*.js,-*.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

Well , you can use regular expression for this in sublime [image]

For different types of regular expressions and case sensitive methods you can refer below url :
https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Configuring/Exclude_or_filter_files_using_file_type_and_regular_expressions
Hope this will help.

Comment: yah i know about regex expression using it but this is not enough. that's why asked above question :) thanks for your efforts